# SSL Certificate not working with Azure VM running application

Tags: azure, ssl, https

Running an Azure VM, hosting a standalone application.
VM is running Server 2012 R2, No IIS.

The application listens on a custom port, say port 3246 for example.

I have configured the VM Endpoint for port 3246.

I have installed a certificate in the local machine store.

I have bound that certificate to port 3246.

I have even uploaded the certificate to the virtual machine cloud service for this VM.

When I run an SSL Scan, all ciphers return either rejected (SSLv2) or Failed (SSLv1 and TLSv1)

When I try connecting to the VM via OpenSSL I get the following:

> 11636:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:.\ssl\s23_clnt.c:794:
>
> ```
>  --- no peer certificate available
>  --- No client certificate CA names sent    
>  --- SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 347 bytes
>  --- New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)    Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
>  Compression: NONE
>  Expansion: NONE
>  No ALPN negotiated
> ```

It appears that the SSL certificate is not being used?

I have tried setting up ACL on the VM endpoint for port 3246, and also using no ALC, which should allow all traffic through.

Windows Firewall on the VM is set to allow traffic for port 3246, but I have also tried with the firewall disabled.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!